# Outlook Client plugin/addin URL Redirection

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010, outlook-restapi, crm-outlook-client

I can't seem to redirect to a specific web url using outlook client plugin/addin. Example I have `https://test.com/#/players/test-url/true` bind to my 'displayLink' button, whenever I click the button it redirects to me to this url `https://test.com`. Why does it remove the `/#/players/test-url/true`? Do i need to configure my manifest file to allow it to redirect to a specific URL? My Office version is 1807 (Build 10325.20082)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some version of outlook client doesn't support URL fragment. So what I did I converted the URL into tinyURL, I used this [image] to create the URL.